# Typeset author list with affiliations, equal contribution footnote, and "work done while at Institute" footnote

Tags: footnotes, author, affiliation

I'd like to typeset an author list with

- affiliations (right below the author list)

  - all but 2 authors share affiliation A; the remaining 2 authors have 2 affiliations
- equal contribution footnote for two authors
- "work done while at Institute" footnote for one author

**What's the most non-confusing way to type set this? And how to do it?**

Visually, I'm imagining one possibility is:

```
John D^*    Mary G^*    ...    AuthorA^\dagger     Jack M    Michelle K    AuthorB^\S

InstituteA     ^\dagger InstituteB     ^\S InstituteC

Footnotes:
^* Equally contributed.
^\dagger Work done while at InstituteA.
```

**My concern is that `\dagger` is used for both the affiliation line as well as  a footnote symbol, which may be confusing?**

Alternatives considered:

- Use number "1" as an additional footnote symbol for "Work done while at InstituteA." This may be confusing too, because the other footnote symbol `*` is not a number.
- Make the two footnote symbols "1" and "2", but it seems quite weird to use "1" for an "equal contribution" note.
- Use footnote symbols `*` and `\dagger` for the two footnotes, and for the affiliation marks: add "1" to many authors for InstituteA (quite a few repetitions), add "2"/"3" to one author each for Institute A/B .
- Use footnote symbols `*` and `\dagger` for the two footnotes, and for the affiliation marks: add "1"/"2" to one author each for Institute B/C.